# Doubling vowels of words in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to create a method that doubles vowels of a word that the user enters, for example:

`Car->Caar
 Love->loovee`

How do I do this?

Comment: You can write code that does that.

Comment: use `.toCharArray()` and `if conditions`

Answer (score 1):

```
yourWord = yourWord.replaceAll("a", "aa") // iterate this accross all vowels and cases
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "car";
String output = "";
for(int i=0 ; i< input.length(); i++){
  if((input.charAt(i)+"").toUpperCase().matches("A|E|I|O|U")){
     output += input.charAt(i);
  }
  output += input.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Now how could I reverse this?
For example, caar ->car